# Action Script to java script - string to string translation

Tags: javascript, string, actionscript, replace, translation

I need this, can it be added an option like, split and join again I don;t know that much of this but I saw an action script with that option it was " a,b,c " 
here is the actionscript code but I want it in javascript please help me get it...

```
tIn.onChanged = function()
{
    var sInput = tIn.text; //Gets the text from the first text field.
    sInput = translate(sInput); //Goes through the translator.
    tOut.text = sInput; //Sets the second text field to the translated text.
}
function translate(sInput)
{
    //This is where you add how you want your text changed.
    //It should be in the format of
    //sInput = searchAndReplace(sInput, What you want changed, What you want it changed             to);
//Remember to use quotes around the text you are changing.
    sInput = searchAndReplace(sInput, "how r u sis", "how are you sister ");
    sInput = searchAndReplace(sInput, "how r u bro", "how are you brother ");
    sInput = searchAndReplace(sInput, "whatsup ", "what is up ");
    return sInput;
}
function searchAndReplace(a, b, c) //Searches string a for b and replaces it with c
{
    tmp = a.split(b); //Splits a into an array of values where b is.
    a = tmp.join(c); //Joins them back together with c seperating them.
    return (a); //Returns the changed string.
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in JS, just instead of .text you should place it in an html element (use getElementById).    
Anyway you can shorten it in:  
`sInput = sInput.split("how r u sis").join("how are you sister ").split("how r u bro").join("how are you brother ").split("whatsup ").join("what is up ");`

Comment: Hi @Nadia thanks for the fast answer but I am still having some issues here is the code : http://raadso.net/tests/translate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First... if you want to execute the script while you type, you have no reason to add the "search" button.
Anyway, here is the code on input field (as you type) AND on search button, chose what you want to use:

```
    <input id="sInput" type="text"  onkeydown="translate()">
    <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="translate()">
```

Than, AFTER this code and AFTER the div "result", you have to add the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function translate()
    {
        var sInput = document.getElementById('sInput').value; 
        sInput = sInput.split("how r u sis").join("how are you sister ").split("how r u bro").join("how are you brother ").split("whatsup ").join("what is up ");
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =sInput;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want it working on paste too, add this code to the input field:  `onpaste="translate()" oninput="translate()"` (depending on browser you need oninputo or onpaste)

Comment: I have a database too with alot of strings : word_title and Word_desc, can you help me connect to this data base too. or give me an example link that i can follow thanks again Nadia

Comment: Sure! My fee is 30€/h :-)

Comment: can i pay you through Paypal if not tell me any other ways you can get payments... thanks

Comment: I was joking :-) just to say that you can't ask someone to do your job :-) write a specific question on the problem you get and you will  for sure get the answers you need